# Adding time from a time picker to EditTextPrefrence

Tags: android, android-edittext

So, I'am writing a code to pick a time a from the timepicker and add this text to the edittextprefrence, I'am not able to do this for some reason.

This is my code to add time from a time picker to edittextprefrence

```
public class extra extends PreferenceActivity {


//private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener;

private EditTextPreference from;
private EditTextPreference to;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.extra);


    final timeSelector ts = new timeSelector();

    from =(EditTextPreference) findPreference("camera-service-time_from");
    //to = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("camera-service-time_to") ;

    from.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            String put = ts.timeSel();


            Log.d("TEST2:",put);
            from.setText(put);
            setPreferenceScreen(null);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.extra);
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

My time picker code:

```
public class timeSelector
{

    int pickdhr;
    int pickdmin;


    String timeSel()
    {

        //here
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(extra.this,
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                          int minute) {

                        pickdhr= hourOfDay;
                       pickdmin= minute;



                    }
                }, mHour, mMinute, true);
        timePickerDialog.show();

        Log.d("TEST3:",pickdhr+":"+pickdmin);
        return pickdhr+":"+ pickdmin;
    }


}
```

}

So, I am not able to add the selected time to the edittextprefrence where did I go wrong?

Comment: any error you're receiving  ?

Comment: no error, I have edited it a bit though.Using ` int pickdhr;
        int pickdmin;` as global variables.

Comment: everytime I am doing this `  String put = ts.timeSel(); from.setText(put);
                setPreferenceScreen(null);
                addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.extra);
                return false;`    in `  from.setOnPreferenceClickListener()` the time picker is not showing up.

Comment: setting time in `EditText` properly ?

Comment: setting time for EditTextPreference

Comment: Code looks fine . why are you using `setText` again in `setOnPreferenceClickListener`

Comment: see my new code edited it.....it's still not working, the time picker is not working from the next time once the `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.extra);` is executed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182258/discussion-between-ali-ahmed-and-shriyans-varma).